# Unbanning members on event from Discord server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made the event `guildBanAdd` to unban specific ids, but I want it to unban only those ids that got banned, because for the ids that didn't get banned I get the error of an unknown ban.

```js
const cool = ['607868627181502467', '638038115277340723', '347651751651966978'];
const { Client, guild, Message } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
  name: 'guildBanAdd',
  execute(message, guild, member, client) {
    cool.forEach((fB) => {
      message.guild.members.unban(fB);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simply checking the guild's bans will help

```js
const cool = ['607868627181502467', '638038115277340723', '347651751651966978']

module.exports = {
  name: 'guildBanAdd',
  async execute(message, guild, member, client) {
    const guildBans = await message.guild.bans.fetch()
    //await message.guild.fetchBans() on v12
    cool.forEach((fB)=>{
      if(guildBans.has(fB)) message.guild.members.unban(fB)
    })
  }
}
```

## Docs

`Guild.bans`: [docs for v13](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=bans)

`Guild.fetchBans()`: [docs for v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBans)

Comment: It's still trying to unban every id from the array

Comment: I'm trying to make it so it will not try to unban every id, only those ids that are banned

Comment: Whoops, my bad... I wasn't supposed to add the `!`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!